# paypal Rest Api error The request was aborted: The request was canceled. Cannot close stream until all bytes are written

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, paypal, express-checkout

I have a problem . 
When I try a payment with paypal ( rest api  & PaypalCoreSDK version is 1.3.4.0 , RestApiSDK  versiyon is  0.7.3.0)  on my website project ( .net 4.0 aspx webform ) I have a problem , error message  . 
but sometimes running smoothly
This message is ;

```
{"The request was aborted: The request was canceled."}
{"Cannot close stream until all bytes are written."}
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
   at PayPal.HttpConnection.Execute(String payLoad, HttpWebRequest httpRequest)
   at PayPal.PayPalResource.ConfigureAndExecute[T](APIContext apiContext, HttpMethod httpMethod, String resource, Dictionary`2 headersMap, String payLoad)
   at PayPal.PayPalResource.ConfigureAndExecute[T](APIContext apiContext, HttpMethod httpMethod, String resource, String payLoad)
   at PayPal.Api.Payments.Payment.Create(APIContext apiContext)
   at DEPOSANAT.Web.CheckOut.PaymentWithPaypal(String totalAmount, String amountCurrency, String amountDetailShipping, String amountDetailSubTotal, String amountDetailTax, String orderID, String recipientName, String shipingAddressLine1, String shipingAddressLine2, List`1 shoppinListItems) in C:\Users\tahsin.ozcelik\Desktop\DEPOSANAT_Proj_TFS\DEPOSANAT\DEPOSANAT.Web\CheckOut.aspx.cs:line 181
   at DEPOSANAT.Web.CheckOut.imgBtnPaypalOdeme_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in C:\Users\tahsin.ozcelik\Desktop\DEPOSANAT_Proj_TFS\DEPOSANAT\DEPOSANAT.Web\CheckOut.aspx.cs:line 94
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

My codes ;

```
private static string GetAccessToken()
    { 
        string accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential("XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXX", GetConfig()).GetAccessToken();
        return accessToken;
    }
    public static APIContext GetAPIContext()
    {
        APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(GetAccessToken());
        apiContext.Config = GetConfig();
        return apiContext;
    }
    private static Dictionary<string, string> GetConfig()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> configMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        configMap.Add("mode", "sandbox");
        configMap.Add("connectionTimeout", "36000");
       return configMap;
    }
```

APIContext apiContext = GetAPIContext();

```
        ProductLBll pLBll = new ProductLBll();
        List<Item> itms = new List<Item>();
        decimal productTotal = 0;
        foreach (var myObj in shoppinListItems)
        {
            Item myAddItem = new Item();
            myAddItem.currency = amountCurrency;
            myAddItem.name = pLBll.GetName(VariableHelper.CheckValueOfInt(myObj.ProductVariant.ProductId), SessionUser.LanguageTypeId);//pLBll.GetName(VariableHelper.CheckValueOfInt(myObj.ProductVariant.ProductId), SessionUser.LanguageTypeId);
            myAddItem.price = String.Format("{0:0.00}", myObj.ProductVariant.CurrentAmount.Value);//String.Format("{0:0.00}", myObj.ProductVariant.CurrentAmount.Value);
            myAddItem.quantity = shoppinListItems[0].Qtty.ToString();//myObj.Qtty.ToString();
            myAddItem.sku = myObj.ProductVariant.ProductId.HasValue ? myObj.ProductVariant.ProductId.Value.ToString() : "ID YOK";
            productTotal += myObj.ProductVariant.CurrentAmount.Value * myObj.Qtty;//myObj.ProductVariant.CurrentAmount.Value * myObj.Qtty;
            itms.Add(myAddItem);
        }

       ItemList itemList = new ItemList();
        itemList.items = itms;


        Payer payr = new Payer();
        payr.payment_method = "paypal";

        string baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/odeme?";
        string requestUrl = Request.Url.OriginalString;
        orderID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string returnUrl = baseURI + "snc=true";
        //+ orderID.Substring(0, 10);
        string cancelUrl = baseURI + "snc=false";
        //+orderID.Substring(0, 13);
        RedirectUrls redirUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        redirUrls.cancel_url = cancelUrl;
        redirUrls.return_url = returnUrl;

        Details details = new Details();
        details.tax = String.Format("{0:0.00}", amountDetailTax);
       details.shipping = String.Format("{0:0.00}", amountDetailShipping);
        details.subtotal = String.Format("{0:0.00}", productTotal);



        decimal total = VariableHelper.CheckValueOfDecimal(details.tax) + VariableHelper.CheckValueOfDecimal(details.shipping) + productTotal;
        Amount amnt = new Amount();
        amnt.currency = amountCurrency;
        amnt.total = total.ToString();
        amnt.details = details;

        List<Transaction> transactionList = new List<Transaction>();
        Transaction tran = new Transaction();
        tran.description = "işlem açıklaması";
        tran.amount = amnt;
        tran.item_list = itemList;

        transactionList.Add(tran);


        Payment pymnt = new Payment();
        pymnt.intent = "sale";
        pymnt.payer = payr;
        pymnt.transactions = transactionList;
        pymnt.redirect_urls = redirUrls;
        #endregion

        string redirectUrl = "";
        try
        {
            Payment createdPayment = pymnt.Create(apiContext);
            foreach (var itemm in createdPayment.links)
            {
                if (itemm.rel.Contains("approval_url"))
                    redirectUrl = itemm.href;
            }
        }
        catch (PayPal.Exception.PayPalException ex)
        {
            //Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

Can you help me quickly ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue.
For me it turned out to be caused by certain characters in the description of the transaction and the items within the transaction. Eg. 'The Euro sign', á é ä etcetera.

Seems like the encoding of this is not handled (correctly) by the library.

Answer (score 0):

Jan is exactly right, and thank you for that important lead.

I have been struggling with this occasional error for a few days since I went live with a new payment form last week. As it turns out many international addresses contain letters which contain diacritical marks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic). I confirmed this problem in the paypal sandbox by using these characters in my post data and repeatedly got the exact error you describe above. I too am using the same libraries you describe above.

To attempt to solve this issue (works in all tests so far) I'm scrubbing my user input (address line 1, line 2, first_name, last_name, etc) in the following method

```
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx
    String NormalizeString(String value)
    {
        if (!value.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            var newStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            newStringBuilder.Append(value.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD)
                                            .Where(x => x < 128)
                                            .ToArray());
            return newStringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        return value;
    }
```